# The context cannot be used while the model is being created

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, parallel-processing

error is : The context cannot be used while the model is being created.

I'm using this code :

```
Parallel.Invoke(AddDataParallel);



  private void AddDataParallel()
    {
        Parallel.For(1001, 2001, delegate(int i)
                                     {
                                         User user = new User();
                                         user.UserName = "user" + i;
                                         _userService2.Add(user);
                                     });

    }
```

error :

```
public T Add(T entity)
    {
        return _entities.Add(entity);//The context cannot be used while the model is being created.
    }
```

why ?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use only one context instance (wrapped in `_userService2`). But an `ObjectContext` (or `DbContext`) is not thread-safe as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx). See Remarks:

> The ObjectContext class is not thread safe. The integrity of data objects in an ObjectContext cannot be ensured in multithreaded scenarios.

So you have to re-design your insert scenario. Parallellization against a database is always tricky as you make yourself your own concurrent user. If you want fast inserts, take a look at [`BulkInsert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.tasks.bulkinserttask.bulkinserttask.aspx).